# glade and glade-previewer (v3.40.0) output missing icons errors

Tags: glade

When I pass glade-previewer v3.40.0 on a .glade file, on MYSYS2, like so

```
 glade-previewer.exe --filename gui_file.glade
```

I get the error messages

```
GladeUI-Message: 18:11:25.933: 1 missing displayable value for GtkWidget::AtkObject::accessible-role
GladeUI-Message: 18:11:26.509: 5 missing displayable value for GtkCellRendererText::variant
GladeUI-Message: 18:11:26.622: Glade needs artwork; a default icon will be used for the following classes:
        GFileIcon       needs an icon named 'widget-gtk-fileicon'
        GThemedIcon     needs an icon named 'widget-gtk-themedicon'
        GladeInstantiableGtkBin needs an icon named 'widget-gtk-bin'
        GtkFileChooserNative    needs an icon named 'widget-gtk-filechoosernative'
        GtkApplicationWindow    needs an icon named 'widget-gtk-applicationwindow'
```

Launching glade itself also output a similar list of errors:

```
GladeUI-Message: 18:24:39.797: 1 missing displayable value for GtkWidget::AtkObject::accessible-role
GladeUI-Message: 18:24:40.594: 5 missing displayable value for GtkCellRendererText::variant
GladeUI-Message: 18:24:40.729: Glade needs artwork; a default icon will be used for the following classes:
        GladeInstantiableGtkBin needs an icon named 'widget-gtk-bin'
        GFileIcon       needs an icon named 'widget-gtk-fileicon'
        GtkFileChooserNative    needs an icon named 'widget-gtk-filechoosernative'
        GThemedIcon     needs an icon named 'widget-gtk-themedicon'
        GtkApplicationWindow    needs an icon named 'widget-gtk-applicationwindow'
GladeUI-Message: 18:24:40.781: No DevHelp installed on your system, devhelp feature will be disabled.
```

What can do the fix this issue? I have tried upgrading all the packages on MSYS2 but that didn't work.